# Can't re-post deleted question

Tags: support

I've posted a question.

I immediately deleted it because I realized that I forgot to publish a test page mentionned in the question.

Now the problem is fixed and I'm trying to ask the question again.

But's it doesn't want to post the question, it says it's a dupplicate of the question... which is deleted.

Here is the link that appears in the red box that tells me that it's a duplicate:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35927/why-do-people-always-comment-google-posts-i-drop-to-market-my-blog-instead-of-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's kind of mean of the system; it doesn't show you your own deleted posts (unless you have 10,000 rep) so you can't undelete unless you still have the page up.

I've [undeleted the post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35927/why-do-people-always-comment-google-posts-i-drop-to-market-my-blog-instead-of-m) so you can make any changes necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much ;=)